# 'Permission Denied' Error when getting a file via SFTP

Tags: unix, sftp, chmod

On a unix host, I'm logged in as 'userA' and have a directory 'test' with permission of

> drwxrwxrwx

I can create a file in 'test' dir fine.

I then sftp to a remote box, with 'userB' (sftp userB@remotebox), and successfully Cd'ed into a remote dir on that box and can see files in that remote dir. I then do 'get myFile' from that remote dir, and I get this message:

> Fetching /remoteDir/myFile to myFile Couldn't get handle: Permission
>   denied

What do I need to check?

Comment: Does the userB have the necessary permissions to read the file in the remoteBox?

Comment: I think i know why: the file i'm trying to get on the remote box is:  -rwxrwx---  and 'userB' does not belong to the group of that file's owner. Is that the reason?

Comment: @user1008636: Yes it is. chmod 644 the file itself.

Answer (score 3):

```
Couldn't get handle: Permission denied
```

"Couldn't get handle" means the sftp client couldn't get a handle to the remote resource. The resource in this case is the file which you're trying to get. "Permission denied" is a standard message meaning that your remote user ID doesn't have permission to access the file in question.

As you noted in a comment:

> the file i'm trying to get on the remote box is: -rwxrwx--- and 'userB' does not belong to the group of that file's owner.

so "userB" in fact doesn't have permission to read the remote file.

Answer (score 3):

Try setting permissions to 755 (-rwxr-xr-x) on the user's home directory.

Answer (score 0):

Same problem, lack of read Permission ,I was trying download a certs.
What I did is cp the file I want to download to users directory and set permissions to 777(755 is ok as mentioned)`chmod 777 filepath`, then I can download it .

Answer (score -1):

The problem is with upload permissions to the remote directory. Check that you have appropriate write permissions for the remote directory.